# Cursor incorrect integer value error

Tags: mysql

I am trying to make my first cursor in MySQL and I am receiving an error. It says incorrect integer value. I was thinking this would grab the value in row one from column customer_Id, and store it into the IdValue variable. How do I code this correctly and fix this error?

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE CursorProcedure()
BEGIN
DECLARE IdValue int;
DECLARE  myCursor CURSOR FOR 
SELECT customer_Id FROM customers;

OPEN myCursor;
FETCH myCursor INTO IdValue;
CLOSE myCursor;
SELECT IdValue;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS CursorProcedure;
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE CursorProcedure()
BEGIN
    DECLARE done INT DEFAULT FALSE;
    DECLARE IdValue int;
    DECLARE myCursor CURSOR FOR SELECT customer_Id FROM customers;
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE;

    OPEN myCursor;
    read_loop: LOOP
        FETCH myCursor INTO IdValue;
        IF done THEN
            LEAVE read_loop;
        END IF;
        -- 
        --  YOU ARE IN YOUR READ LOOP
        --  DO SOMETHING WITH IT HERE
        --
    END LOOP;
    CLOSE myCursor;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

But in the "do something with it here", don't do a SELECT on it because it will generate multiple result sets. Do something meaningful.

Manual page on [Cursors](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/cursors.html).

As an aside, cursors are rarely your friends. They are extremely slow. Use them in dire emergencies only.

Comment: I did 'Set IdValue= IdValue;
INSERT INTO customers (newCol) Values (IdValue);' for the loop body. When I run it, it inserts the values randomly and starts at a row 5. Why would this be?

Comment: Please join me [here](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95290/campaigns) in chat